# How is a client query distributed across a Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

Can anyone please explain to me how a client query is distributed in a Cassandra cluster?

In my set-up I have three nodes (A, B and C) and data is shared evenly across all nodes. I am running Python server code on another PC (D). When a client sends a request to D, how does the Cassandra cluster distribute the client query?

Comment: The client sends a query to one of the available nodes (I assume you have set up a connection to the cluster and a connection pool.) The node that received the request becomes the 'coordinator'. The coordinator hashes the token from the primary key and figures out which node(s) have the data. Based on the consistency level and replication factor, the coordinator waits for acknowledgements from the required number of nodes. The result is then returned to the client.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably depend on how your python server is configured.  If it's using the Datastax python driver, then there are various load balancing options that can be configured to tell the driver how you want queries to be load balanced.

For example cassandra.policies.RoundRobinPolicy would iterate over the available Cassandra nodes to send each query to a different node.

Or cassandra.policies.TokenAwarePolicy would figure out which nodes have replicas for the target partition and contact those nodes directly (i.e. skip contacting nodes that do not have the target partition).

The available load balancing policies can sometimes be combined.

For more information see [this](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/policies.html#load-balancing).

Comment: Thanks Jim,I have  understood this concepts....but if i have a set up like two nodes A and B. Initially A with full data i.e., means there is no cluster set up, and i added node B to the cluster with existing node A.Now in this set up , how the client query is disributed when both the nodes having 100 % data ?

Comment: It depends on what replication factor you are using.  If you use replication factor 1, then the two nodes would split the data, and each node would handle approximately half of the queries.  If you used a replication factor of 2, then each node would have a full copy of the data, and when you did a write, both nodes would see the write, and when you did a read, then either node could handle the read.